# How to save state of app on application exit

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on an iphone game app. I dont want to use core data or nsuserdefaults to store user data. instead i want to keep all activities in memory and then send it to server when user goes back to previous screen, ends game or presses the home button of iphone. Now everything works fine but i am not able to sync user data when user presses home button. I have implemented the appilcationWillTerminate method in my delegate class but its not working out for me as the method is not get called when I press home button of iphone. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this task?

best regards

Comment: Did you try applicationDidEnterBackground:?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this method:

*Tells the delegate that the application is now in the background.*

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

From Apple Docs:

> In iOS 4.0 and later, this method is called instead of the applicationWillTerminate: method when the user quits an application that supports background execution. You should use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. You should also disable updates to your application’s user interface and avoid using some types of shared system resources (such as the user’s contacts database). It is also imperative that you avoid using OpenGL ES in the background.
>
> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If you need additional time to perform any final tasks, you can request additional execution time from the system by calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:. In practice, you should return from applicationDidEnterBackground: as quickly as possible. If the method does not return before time runs out your application is terminated and purged from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSUserDefaults to store data about the application state. Then, when the application re-starts, you can load the data from NSUserDefaults to recreate the previous state. However with the new multitasking this is not as necessary as it used to be a couple of years ago.